# typescript inferring method return type in inheriting class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a base class with a property of the return type of another method in the same class, which can change it's type in subclasses:

```
abstract class Base {
    public get = {
        ...this.getBase(),
        hello() {}
    }

    protected abstract getBase<T extends object>(): T;
}

class InheritBase extends Base {
    // Error: '{ hello2(): number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'
    protected getBase() {
        return {
            hello2() {return 3},
        }
    }
}

class InheritBase2 extends Base {
    // Error: '{ differentHello(): number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'
    protected getBase() {
        return {
            differentHello() {return 4},
        }
    }
}

const c = new InheritBase();
// ok
c.get.hello();
// Error: hello2 doesn't exist on property get
c.get.hello2();

const d = new InheritBase2();
// ok
d.get.hello();
// Error: differentHello doesn't exist on property get
d.get.differentHello();
```

The idea is to avoid redefining the property `get` in every subclass while also getting the actual type in the derived class.
How can this be achieved?